# Миграция БД в EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net

Доброго времени суток уважаемые форумчане!
Столкнулся с проблемой, при написании программы с использованием code-first, подключил миграцию. При внесении изменений в модель в коде и включения миграции в таблице Roly(роли пользователей), рандомно дублируется одна из записей и валит всю программу в Error, до тех пор пока не удалишь дублирующую роль.Может кто встречался с такой проблемой, подскажите, как исправить....
За ранее спасибо:)

Comment: antei23 спасибо за ссылку:) сам этот сайт почитываю:)
вот и я думал, что так оно и есть и вроде ничего такого не вносил...а вот поле создается(...надо будет наверное попробовать рубануть все записи и проверить миграцию) может и правда где-то напутано с ID)
Еще раз спасибо большое:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А как у вас там дубль записи появляется, миграция же просто изменяет структуру базы данных, не внося никаких вставок в бд? Может вы что-то не то сделали? По миграции можно посмотреть [тут](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/5.12.php)

Когда идет миграция, вы просто добавляете столбцы или таблицы, а даные остаются теми же. И если вы правильно задали поле Id при миграции, что оно будет идентификатором, то дубляжа строк не должно быть.